# Sequelize add type cast on association

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

Is there any way to explicitly add type casts on sequelize when defining association? 
The Transaction Details table and Products table have 1:M association and they are defined like this:

```
db.models.TransactionDetails.hasMany(db.models.Products,{
    sourceKey: 'productId', //this has a data type of character varying
    foreignKey: 'recordId' // this is bigint
});
```

I am getting the error "SequelizeDatabaseError: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts." when I'm doing include because they have different data types. Altering the table on postgres won't be a solution because this is only on localhost.

Comment: got any solutions to the issue i am also looking fo this one

Comment: I just did a migration to change the data type of productId. If that's not your option then you maybe need to use raw query to type cast but I'm not sure

Comment: Hey, got any solution I am also facing this error, I want to run the query without changing dataType

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working, looks something like this:

```js
const items = await MyModel.findAll({
  ...
  include: [{
    model: OtherModel,
    on: sequelize.literal('"MyModel"."id" = "OtherModel"."some_column"::text');
  }]
});
```

Comment: This trick worked for me, thanks! However I had to define the association as well, otherwise sequelize complains that the models are not associated. And the association obviously doesn't work without using this "on" option in every query.