# Include foreign key having different type in sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two Tables Games and Quiz

Quiz has foreign key (`gameId`) of Games Table and having data type character varying

So when i try to include the model Game

```
Quiz.findAndCountAll({
  include: [{ model: Games }],
});
```

It gives error `No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

I have defined associations like this:

```
Quiz.belongsTo(models.Games, { foreignKey: "gameId" });

Games.hasMany(models.Quiz, {
   foreignKey: {name: "gameId"},
   as: "Quiz",
   onDelete: "CASCADE"
});
```

I came across similar stackoverflow question: [Sequelize add type cast on association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462949/sequelize-add-type-cast-on-association)

but there are no answers to this question

When i run query on PG Admin

[image: Query]

Comment: Instead of searching for a possibility to cast, you should rather fix the schema so that the types are the same...

Comment: but currently there are so many existing rows would that be affected if i update the type ?

Comment: Depends on the types but when the `=` doesn't work they're likely not that easy to change. The existence of many rows doesn't make the usage of different types any better though. How would you even successfully add a foreign key constraint in your situation? I guess there is none? Which is the next bad thing...

Comment: And if you do not fix the data types how many rows will you have the next time the fix is needed.  And you can guarantee there will be.  And thenas @stickybit points out you will be able to have referential integrity (FKs). The proper solution is never the wrong choice, but always harder after each band-aid is applied.